# Full-mesh of Access Switches vs. Uplinking to Distribution Switches

Tags: switch, lan, wan, uplinks

I'm reading Cisco CCENT/CCNA guide for Interconnecting Cisco Network Devices 1 100-101 (Odem)

Chapter 6 explains that Campus LAN with 2 Distribution Switches and 40 Access switches uses 4 * 40 = 160 cables, but without Distribution Switches, the Access switches use 780 links.

I don't understand how they got 780 links. If it's relevant, the 40 access switches connect to 1000 PCs

I've been wracking my mind over this .... help!

[image]

Comment: This topology is wrong.  Notice the access switch on the left links to a single distribution switch?  That's a single point of failure.

Comment: @RonRoyston This is a theoretical drawing from the book

Comment: It an important question - how to correctly uplink IDFs to MDFs.  However, that book appears to need some technical review/editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the number of links in a fully meshed topology of N devices, the formula is this:

```
Full-mesh links = (N)*(N-1)/2
```

Substituting numbers...

```
                = 40*39/2
                = 780
```

However, you'd only have one link to every switch if calculated thusly.  If you assume 4 links per switch, it's technically 4*780, or 3120 uplinks.

Comment: How old is that text?  These days the access switches would have dual 40G uplinks, one to each of the distribution switches in a LAG that spans distribution switch chassis for a total of 40*2 or 80 40G uplinks (40 per distribution switch) and maybe 4 40G links interconnecting the distribution switches.  Access switches would be 10/100/1000/10000

Comment: @georgeb, I wouldn't read too much into the uplink sizes... if it's a CCENT text, they're just teaching networking concepts.

Comment: @georgeb This text is to study for Cisco entry exam ...